# Using libGDX for developing social games for iOS

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, libgdx

I was using XCode and SpriteKit for developing iOS games that could implement Facebook and Parse (analytics). Because everything was in XCode and Objective-C, I had no problem with Facebook and Parse SDK.
Recently, I decided to use libGDX and I have to write code in Java (I started using Eclipse). Because I am fairly new in this area I was wondering what happens to implementation of Facebook and Parse SDK? Could I just write an Objective-C class in Eclipse that includes these two and use its methods in Java???!! Any other magic or trick you could think of, I really appreciate it if you could share it with me.